# Metabase - create filter from json field

Tags: mysql, metabase, json-extract

Is there a way to add a filter based on extracted data from a json field? currently I can do something like

```
json_extract(meta, '$.mp_origin_meta') AS booking_type)
```

or

```
meta->'$.mp_origin_meta'
```

to extract specific data by writing a native query, but I really want to add this like a filter to my dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using our analytics script which sends our data to Metabase. Generally, we have to create a virtual field in our table and add the json extracted value to that new field. I did this programmatically with a PHP script, but there must be a way to add a field via Metabase panel.